# Possible to create a grouped product for grouped products?

Tags: magento, php

I was wondering if anyone's tried or knows if it's possible to create a grouped product, and display grouped product items within that grouped product.  Magento by default doesn't allow you to choose grouped products in 'Associated Products' in the admin - only simple products.  One thing I tried doing was editing the 'grouped.phtml' file in my template and creating three separate data-tables and assigning specific associated products to them, but I can't seem to make that happen. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no native APIs that allow this.  You'd need to write your own "GroupedGroup Product" object, and then write template code to display it and post to the cart correctly.  (each of which is multiple questions)